# Convert String from ANSI(Windows-1252) to UTF - 8

Tags: java, utf-8

> I have the following String date = "13 - فبراير ",

And a map for the months with the following encoding:

```
    Map<Integer, String> months = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    months.put(1, "ÙŠÙ†Ø§ÙŠØ±");
    months.put(2, "ÙØ¨Ø±Ø§ÙŠØ±");
    months.put(3, "Ù…Ø§Ø±Ø³");
    months.put(4, "Ø§Ø¨Ø±ÙŠÙ„");
    months.put(5, "Ù…Ø§Ø¨Ùˆ");
    months.put(6, "ÙŠÙˆÙ†ÙŠÙˆ");
    months.put(7, "ÙŠÙˆÙ„ÙŠÙˆ");
    months.put(8, "Ø§ØºØ³Ø·Ø³");
    months.put(9, "Ø³Ø¨ØªÙ…Ø¨Ø±");
    months.put(10, "Ø§ÙƒØªÙˆØ¨Ø±");
    months.put(11, "Ù†ÙˆÙÙ…Ø¨Ø±");
    months.put(12, "Ø¯ÙŠØ³Ù…Ø¨Ø±");
```

what iam looking for is to determine the month for the input

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : months.entrySet()) {
            int key = entry.getKey();
            String value = months.get(key);
            if (input.contains(value)) {
                System.out.println("YES");
                break;
        } 
   }
```

But the condition is never true because the encoding is different, so i have to convert every month from ANSI to UTF-8 to be able to get the correct month.

I have tried the following:

```
    byte[] ptext = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("windows-1252")); 
    String value = new String(ptext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
    System.out.println(value);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but already failed to save your example using Eclipse, at it already complains that the strings contained in the `put` commands of you Map cannot be converted properly using UTF-8 (mixture of UTF-8 and CP1252). As such I already suspect that this might already be an issue by itself, as the java compiler will have even more problems with it. 
As I don't know the language (arabic?) of the months: can you please post the byte values of the chars in CP1252 encoding here? This would make the life much easier. Thanks!

Comment: **`new String(ptext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` makes no sense** except when pText is text encoded with, well UTF-8, which plainly it's not!

Comment: Why don't you use text normally in your source file, like `months.put(2, "فبراير")`? "ÙØ¨Ø±Ø§ÙŠØ±" is some kind of representation of bytes that for text that is encoded in a weird way. Text datatypes should not be used for bytes.

Comment: Or as `"\u0641\u0628\u0631\u0627\u064A\u0631"`, if you must?